Solve $\int \frac{1+2x^2\ln x+2x^2(x^2-2)\ln^2x+3x^4\ln^4 x}{(1-x^2\ln^2x)^2}\,dx$
$$I=\int
 \frac{1+2x^2\ln x+2x^2(x^2-2)\ln^2x+3x^4\ln^4x}{(1-x^2\ln^2x)^2}\,dx$$
I found this question without any solution, my first attempts included to verify whether this integral had a closed form(in elementary terms), I ran this through Wolfram and other Integral solvers, none of them returned anything.
I have been trying to manipulate it but I am not quite able to figure out when to begin substituting. Moreover, in an attempt to "break" this single integral into multiple parts and individually computing them(of course first through some software and then manually);
$$I=\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2\ln^2x)^2}\,dx+\int \frac{2x^2(x^2-2)}{(1-x^2\ln^2x)^2}\,dx+\int \frac{2x^2\ln x}{(1-x^2\ln^2x)^2}\,dx+\int \frac{3x^4\ln^4x}{(1-x^2\ln^2x)^2}dx$$
None of the four could be returned back solved and no substitution worked.
I have tried $\ln(x)=t$ , $x\ln x=t$ and $1-x^2\ln^2x=t$ to match the denominator but none of them helped me. It would be great to see a closed form to this integral

Are there supposed to be integral bounds?

No, there weren't any provided. They provided a 'hint' of sorts; stating "Take $x>e$"

Indefinite integrals are usually defined on some connected subset of the domain of whatever function is being integrated. I'm not sure how $x > e$ is a useful hint unless we know what domain $x$ lives in.

I don't even think it's integrable on $(0,2)$, let alone on $(0,\infty)$.

Where did you find this integral?

This may not be helpful, but the square in the denominator suggests the use of Feynman’s technique on $\displaystyle\frac{(\dots)}{1-x^2\ln^2x}$.

@MathGuy an old math competition, unsure of it's name now, regarding the Feynman's Technique, I don't seem to think there's any 'nice' double integral hidden in this, but if you are able to pull it off, ill be really delighted :D

I managed a way to somehow "short" this messier integral. Substitute $2\ln x=z$, then:
$$x^2=e^z\Rightarrow x=e^{\frac z2}$$
$$dx=\frac 12 e^{\frac z2} dz$$
And, if I go along, the above integral becomes:
$$
I=\int \frac{1+2e^z\left(\frac z2\right)+2e^z(e^z-2)\left(\frac z2\right)^2+3e^{2z}\left(\frac z2\right)^4}{\left(1-e^z\left(\frac z2\right)^2\right)^2} \frac{e^{\frac z2}}{2} dz
$$
$$=\frac 12\int \frac{16+16e^zz+8e^z(e^z-2)z^2+3e^{2z}z^4}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)^2} e^{\frac z2}dz
$$
All I am concerned about, is the numerator. I algebraically manipulated it in the form of:
$$
(4-z^2e^z)^2+2ze^z\left(4\left(ze^z+2\right)-z\left(4-z^2e^z\right)\right)
$$
And so, I can rewrite the fraction as:
$$\frac{16+16ze^z+8z^2e^z(e^z-2)+3z^4e^{2z}}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)^2}$$
$$
=\frac{(4-z^2e^z)^2+2ze^z\left(4\left(ze^z+2\right)-z\left(4-z^2e^z\right)\right)}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)^2}
$$
$$
=1+8\frac{ze^z(ze^z+2)}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)^2}-2\frac{z^2e^z}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)}
$$
All I now need is to solve these two integrals,
$$\int \frac{ze^z(ze^z+2)}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)^2} e^{\frac z2}dz$$
and $$\int \frac{z^2e^z}{\left(4-e^zz^2\right)} e^{\frac z2}dz$$
I could not manage any closed form of these. Hopefully, someone on the site will.
